# How much does the size of the array in an array-contains Firestore query impact performance?

Tags: google-cloud-firestore

In an array-contains Firestore query (not array-in or array-contains-any), how much does the size of the array impact the performance of the query? I have five sets of data that I could, for the purposes of this query, combine into a single array. However, if the array-contains query prefers  smaller arrays, I could split the data into five arrays. I'd prefer, for simplicity, to use a single array but I'd rather make Firestore happy, not me. Each set of data has less than 25 elements (so not large at all).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The performance impact is negligible. Each item in the field value is going to be part of a massively scalable index whose performance is not going to be impacted by a few more elements.  Bear in mind also that the maximum total size of a single document is 1MB, so there is really only so much data you can even store in a single field that can compare to the overall size of a collection.

The general performance characteristic of Firestore queries is that they scale with the size of the result set (number of documents matched and returned), not the the size of the source data (total number of documents queried).  The size of a single document's array field doesn't impact this enough to be noticeable.  Feel free to benchmark  if you have concerns.

Comment: Assume a document had a bunch of `Int64` arrays and in total the arrays (in aggregate) had some 1,500 elements. Is that considered by FIrestore to be a big document?

Comment: Documents are never "big" to Firestore.  They have a cap at 1MB in size, and that's it.  The size of a document never impacts the ability of Firestore to scale.

Comment: One last follow up, when we fetch documents and pull them onto the client to parse, as soon as that async `getDocuments` method finishes, Firestore releases all documents from memory, correct? They aren't hung onto or cached, right?

Comment: I think you should ask that as a separate question, show the relevant code you're working with, and explain your concern and observations there.

Comment: Side note : Firestore also has 1500 bytes truncation for field values in an index. While the poster's 25 elements are unlikely to exceed this, for example if I maintain an array of UIDs so I could `array-contains` later who is in it, if UID is around 28 bytes each I could only index about 50 UIDs inside the array. I think this is quite low, as this is likely the way you may want to keep a friend list (list of UID) inside an array. You can keep more than 50 person but index was truncated and you can't use it in a query.

Comment: @5argon So are you suggesting that you have personally observed that strings at the end of large arrays will not be matched by an array-contains? I find that hard to believe. I would fully expect all strings in an array to work fine, up to 1500 bytes in length for each individual string.

Comment: @DougStevenson Hello, no, I am planning my database design as I read this rule and didn't really see "inconsistent result" happening. And I did not know that it is an **individual** string because [storage size calculation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/storage-size#field-size) page suggests that an array field value calculated from sum of its values (therefore array is a "field"), and directly below it says "Note: Field values in an index are truncated after 1500 bytes", so I thought it applies to an entire array not individual items, summing up array size first then truncate.

Comment: @DougStevenson, so does this mean only the deepest field is truncated? Like with the example about having an array of strings, does this mean there can be a top level field storing an array of strings that combined would go over 1500 bytes but individually are less, and they would all get indexed?